# Sum of unique values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have the following collection called `mydata`:

```
{name: 'a', otherStuff: 'blah'},
{name: 'a', otherStuff: 'blah'},
{name: 'b', otherStuff: 'blah'},
{name: 'c', otherStuff: 'blah'},
{name: 'c', otherStuff: 'blah'},
{name: 'a', otherStuff: 'blah'}
```

How can I get the sum of unique `name` values?

For example I'm looking for:

```
{name: 'a', count: 3},
{name: 'b', count: 1},
{name: 'c', count: 2}
```

I've tried searching, but am only seeing results referring to the `distinct` command, which works well to single out the unique values, but nothing explaining how to get the sum of how many times they appear in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

You should use aggregation framework.

Solution for your example:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$name", count: {$sum: 1}}}, 
{$project: {name: "$_id", count: "$count", _id: 0}}]);
```